# Problem in equality in Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

> Let $a>b>0$, $0<p<1$ and let $X$ have $P(X=a)=p$ and $P(X=-b)=1-p$. Apply Chebyshev inequality to $\varphi (x)=(x+b)^2$ and conclude that if $Y$ is any random variable with $E(Y)=E(X)$ and $Var(Y)=Var(X)$ then $P(Y\geq a)\leq p$ and ***equality holds if and only if $Y=X$.***

The first part is easy. But I stuck in the "Equality part". I know that to show to r.v. equal a.s. all you need to show is to show the equality in M.G.F., but here we can not have the M.G.F. of $Y$.

> **Note: Chebyshev’s inequality** :- Suppose $\varphi : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has $\varphi \geq 0$ let $A\in \mathcal{B}$ (Borel set) and let $i_A = \inf \{ \varphi (y) :y\in A \}$.
>
> $i_A P(X\in A) \leq E(\varphi (X), X\in A)\leq E\varphi (X)$

**SOLUTION OF THE INEQUALITY:**

Since $E(Y)=E(X)$ and $Var(Y)=Var(X)$ then $E(Y^2)=E(X^2)$

$i_A P(Y\geq a)\leq E(Y+b)^2=E(X+b)^2=p(a+b)^2$. Here $A=\{ Y\geq a \}$. Then $i_A=(a+b)^2$

So $P(Y\geq a)\leq p\space \space\space\space \blacksquare$

Comment: I'm so confused. $X$ takes on only two values, and $a>b$, so $P(X\geq a)=P(X=a)=p$. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean $P(Y\geq a)\leq p$ instead of $P(X\geq a)\leq p$? Also do you mean "equality holds only when" instead of "equality holds when"?

Comment: Okk, I am adding the solution of the first part!!

Comment: @stewbasic Oh! You are right, I am editing. I wrote what was written in the book(Durrett), if you want to add "only" that will not be a problem (actually what are you saying is precisely right)

Comment: @AlexR. I edited, plizz see now.

Comment: I guess we should interpret "when" as "if and only if", since the "only if" direction is more interesting.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution then the equality is trivial; the interesting thing is that this $X$ *maximizes* $P(X \geq a)$ among all distributions with the given mean and variance.

Comment: @stewbasic I got problem there too, I think it is saying "only if".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the equality case, all the long chain of inequalities becomes a chain of equalities. In particular, $E((Y+b)^2)=E((Y+b)^21_A)=p(a+b)^2$. It follows that $E((Y+b)^2 1_{A^{c}})=0$ where $A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$. The variable $Z=(Y+b)^2 1_{A^{c}}$ is nonnegative with mean $0$, so it must be zero a.s. In other words, we have $(Y+b)^2=0$
(i.e. $Y=-b$) outside of $A$.

Similarly, we have $E((Y+b)^21_A)=E((a+b)^21_A)$ so $E((Y-a)(Y+a+2b)1_A)=0$. The variable $T=(Y-a)(Y+a+2b)1_A$ is nonnegative with mean $0$, so it must be zero a.s. In other words, we have $(Y-a)(Y+a+2b)=0$
(i.e. $Y=a$) on $A$. This finishes the proof.